# How does Nuxt.js Server Side Rendering Work?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I mostly work with Next.js for web projects. Work demands I work on a project that uses Nuxt.js (v2).

I got up to reading on Nuxt. From pouring over the documentation for the last couple of days, there are a few questions that still linger.

1. **Static-Site Generation**: I did dabble in it a few months back, but ended up not using it for anything substantial. It seemed fairly straightforward, not much different from using Next.js for purely static-sites using `getStaticProps()` exclusively for fetching data at build time. Dynamic data fetching and authentication can happen at the client-side very much like it would happen for an SPA. Static data at build time ensures good SEO.
2. **Server-Side Rendering (on Next)**: For Next.js this was simple as well, every time a page is requested `getStaticProps()` will block it from rendering until it can resolve with the props data **on the server itself**. A completely rendered page is returned to the client, from there on out, the client can still call our api routes for immediate dynamic data using XHR.
3. **Server-Side Rendering (on Nuxt)**: Reading the documentation on Nuxt.js and working out a small sample project, Nuxt.js it seems works differently in SSR (universal), only the first request produces a server-rendered page, here on out, both data-fetching functions, `asyncData()` and `fetch()` run on the client-side (javascript bundles for the pages are preloaded using the Nuxt Router).

My question is, what is the benefit of this approach? This will not help out with SEO, secrets can not be stored on the server because the code can execute on the browser. Is there something I am missing? I searched the docs and could not find anything that makes pages render on the server for every request, as a server-rendered application should.

Comment: if you want all pages to render server-side then don't use nuxt-link's throughout, which if you don't then your clearly see why things happen both on the server (initial request), then going forward its done clientside

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That was my initial thought as well. But the docs imply that it is not "efficient", and then there is the issue that one small mistake on the client-side ("to" instead of "href"), can force sensitive code to run on the client, which is not ideal. It would have been great if there were a framework-level switch/mechanism that can guarantee SSR for a page like Next does, but I guess both frameworks follow different design philosophies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm working with Nuxt 3 and as far as I know you can use `useAsyncData()` and `useFetch()` in both client and server. Nuxt 3 SSR universal works fine with SEO because crawlers not cache files so every request is separate, so crawlers get every time SSR HTML file from server. You can use secrets if beside web page you want to create API calls from "server" folder, this is separate functionality to make API calls it not marge with web page. Calling this API will send user only for example JSON file, not whole code from a server/*.js files.

Comment: That is a good point! This is something I had not considered, so this solves the SEO problem, specially for frequently updating data. Which only leaves the limitation (or feature, depending on how you look at it) of code running on the client. I will have to design the application under the bounds of the framework, by looking at it more as an SPA (with SEO!) rather than a "traditional" server rendered app.

Comment: @praet Well it's still sometimes tricky to do it both ways. You can end up code working only on the client side or fetching data twice instead of once.